# Symfony2, Doctrine2 and PostgreSQL: error "Undefined variable: className"

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to configure entities for existing table in PostgreSQL database.
Sequences in this database have names other than default doctrine names, so i have to account that in entity.

```
Webclient\db\LoginBundle\Entity\WebclientUsers:
type: entity
table: webclient.t_webclientusers
fields:
  id:
    type: integer
    generator:
      strategy: AUTO
    sequenceGenerator:
      sequenceName: webclient.s_webclientusers_id
  email:
    type: text
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I tried also other strategy configurations, but i still having error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: className in ****\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php line 343
```

What can I do with that?

Answer (score 1):

I found an aswer on another website:

This is a internal error of Doctrine2, this bug is now fixed but if not :

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1381

Just edit the file ClassMetadataFactory.php and replace $className by $class->name on line 343, it will fix the problem.

You will probably get another error but this time, this will come from ur app.

Regards.